# C#-how to use the result of an API call multiple times

Tags: c#

I am stuck in a situation like this.
I have 2 methods

```
public class Test
{
   public void Test()
   {
        A();
        B();
   }

    Method A    
    private async Task(returntype) A()   
    {   
       var items = await C();
       var myItems = activityItems.Where(x => x.name="my");  
       return myItems;  
    }

    Method B
    private async Task(returntype) A()      
    {      
       var items = await C();
       var myItems = activityItems.Where(x => x.name="all");  
       return myItems;
    }     

    Method C is await method
    private async Task(ResultList) C()    //appserver call
    {   
       var itemsList= await Ioc.Resolve<IServiceCall>().InvokeAsync<IManager, ResultList>(this.MakeWeakFunc<IManager, ResultList>((service) =>
                                       service.GetCounts()));
       return activityItemsCount; 
    }
}
```

Now I need to call 'C' just once instead of twice(Once from from A and once from B) as explained above.

This is very important because api call is costly and I cant afford to call api twice for doing same work

How can I do that?
For Example:
Api call returns 10 items
A uses first 5 out of 10
B uses next 5 out of 10 items

Comment: Please provide real code, not pseudo code. Please edit your post and differ between text and code. Your problem doesn't seem to be related to async/await. Instead of it your are asking how to use the result of an API call multiple times. Where's the problem?

Comment: So basically you want the method C to cache the results and if A or B make the same API they return the results from the cache rather than calling the API again?

Comment: @JonClarke Is there any way without using local cache. Something like having a private variable say "result". Storing result of api call in this variable and using it in method 'A' and method 'B'

Comment: @PradeepDm not really sure what you mean.  Do you pass parameters to the API call or is it parameterless and always returns the same result for A and B?  Could you replace the pseudo code with real code to give an idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JonClarke I have edited it. What I thought is like making itemsList in c() global and using it in B, instead of calling c() from B again. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @JonClarke Your answer matches my requirement. Thank you. I have another doubt.                                                                                          
What if I Call A() and B() in constructor. Control can get into A() and B() before api call is returned to items(variable mentioned ). Then A() and B() is executed with items=null value.

Comment: @PradeepDm if my answer matches your requirements how come you have selected a different answer as the right one?  Which of the 2 answers are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edited question it is still not obvious what types you are using, but hopefully the following code should be enough to get you going.  Personally I prefer maintaining the cache in the C() method as it's encapsulated in one place and easier to maintain.

```
public class ApiCall
{
    private IEnumerable<Item> _result = null;
    private async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> A()
    {            
        if (_result == null)
        {
            _result = await C();
        }

        var items = _result;
        var myItems = items.Where(x => x.name == "my");
        return myItems;
    }

    //Method B
    private async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> B()
    {
        if (_result == null)
        {
            _result = await C();
        }

        var items = _result;
        var myItems = items.Where(x => x.name == "all");
        return myItems;
    }

    //Method C is await method
    private async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> C()    //appserver call
    {
        var itemsList = await Ioc.Resolve<IServiceCall>().InvokeAsync<IManager, ResultList>(this.MakeWeakFunc<IManager, ResultList>((service) => service.GetCounts()));
        return itemsList;
    }
}
```

**Original Post**

Without knowing how the api works this could be a little difficult, but I'm going to assume you pass the api call a number and you get back a string.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> localCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public string C(int id)
{
    if (localCache.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        return localCache[id];
    }
    else
    {
        string returnedFromApi = SomeApiCall(id);
        localCache.Add(id, returnedFromApi);
        return returnedFromApi;
    }
}
```

This is very basic but would get the job done.  You may want to consider caching to disk or database, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to call 'C' just once instead of twice(Once from from A and once from B) as explained above.

Then call it once, and pass the results to each method. If your old code looked like this:

```
var a = await A();
var b = await B();
```

then your new code could look like this:

```
private async Task<List<TResult>> C();
private async Task<TA> A(List<TResult> items);
private async Task<TB> B(List<TResult> items);

var items = await C();
var a = await A(items);
var b = await B(items);
```

Comment: What if I Call A() and B() in constructor. Control can get into A() and B() before api call is returned to items(variable mentioned above).

Comment: Calling asynchronous methods in a constructor is problematic. I recommend you use [one of these solutions](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).